# Cannot delete some files using SimpleFileVisitor in java.nio.file

Tags: java

I wrote some code to delete some files using the SimpleFileVisitor class.
I can traverse the directory and its subdirectories print their contents but cannot delete the target.

```
// imports go here

class FileVisitorTest
{
    public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("C:\\CMakeFiles"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException{
                if(file.getFileName().endsWith(".rule")) {
                    Files.delete(file);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I checked permissions: I am the administrator/user on the computer.

Some insight about what to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Define "cannot". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely?

Comment: Did you check the file attributes?

Comment: @JBNizet  cannot delete files ending with the extension ".rule" as the if statement clearly stipulate.

Comment: @zlakad I checked using DosFileAttributes right now. everything is ok for both the directory and the file I targeted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `getFileName()`, which returns a `Path`. `Path.endsWith()` does not test if the file name ends with ".rule". It tests if the last segment(s) of the path is ".rule". Use `toString().endsWith(".rule")`.

Comment: IT WORKS. Thanks for the clarification about the inner working of Path.endsWith()